# Validate lua config object

Tags: bash, lua, travis-ci

I want to check if this config file contains errors:

https://github.com/freifunk-kiel/site-ffki/blob/master/site.conf

I think the structure is a **lua dict** object and it looks like this:

```
{
    site_name = 'Freifunk Kiel',
    site_code = 'ffki',

    opkg = {
        openwrt = 'http://opkg.services.ffki/%n/%v/%S/packages',
        extra = {
            modules = 'http://opkg.services.ffki/modules/gluon-%GS-%GR/%S',
        }, 
    }
}
```

how can I validate the config file?

I would like to get an error so I can add Travis-CI to our repository that will tell after every commit.

Comment: I added details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this script `site_config.lua`](https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/gluon/blob/master/scripts/site_config.lua):

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1 lua-cjson
GLUON_SITEDIR="." site_config.lua
```

Which is checking for valid code: it exits with exitstatus `0` if everything is fine or `1` if there is an error.

So only question left: [how do I check for the correct indention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873181/check-if-indentation-is-correct),
if there is a missing bracket or the indention is not fitting our standard of using tabs instead of spaces.